# Unable to change output when using date command piped to md5sum and redirected to an output file

Tags: bash, scripting

**PROBLEM:**

Unable to change output when using date command piped to md5sum and redirected to an output file.

**EXISTING ATTEMPT:**

```
#!/bin/bash
 
x=$(date|md5sum)
 
for i in {1..5}
do
    printf "%s \n" ${x}  >> gen_pass_output.txt
done
 
cat ./gen_pass_output.txt
```

I expect to get 5 different strings in the output file, instead I get the same string repeated.

**EXISTING OUTPUT:**

```
28091a8ca642574da8e94a888ff1df7b
-
28091a8ca642574da8e94a888ff1df7b
-
28091a8ca642574da8e94a888ff1df7b
-
28091a8ca642574da8e94a888ff1df7b
-
28091a8ca642574da8e94a888ff1df7b
-
```

**HOPED FOR RESULT:**

To get the output to be a different value on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You call `date` only once, so it will always have the same value.  You want to move the call to `date` inside the `for` loop.

Howerver, all calls to `date` happen within the same second, hence the exact same result.  Add a `sleep 1` inside your `for` loop.  Or use `date -N` to use nanosecond values.

Fix

```
#!/bin/bash
 
for i in {1..5}
do
    x=$(date|md5sum)
    printf "%s \n" ${x}  >> gen_pass_output.txt
    sleep 1
done
 
cat ./gen_pass_output.txt
```